# I am unable to fetch the page with URL that I have used in the code below

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
package erewards;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class erewards_admin {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        FirefoxDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();


         d1.get("http://www.google.com");  
        // d1.close();
        // System.exit(0);


 } }
```

Below is the error which I am getting at runtime.

```
    error:
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    DAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"7.3.16540.9015","st":1405342340000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0","st":1424934772238,"mt":1424934771658}},"winreg-app-global":{"fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Fiddler2\\FiddlerHook","e":false,"v":"2.4.8.3","st":1415012376210,"mt":1406724252000}}}
    1425038534487   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1425038534492   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534493   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534500   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.3.16540.9015
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/pcs/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3272192605644315779webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
    JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
    *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
    1425038536584   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
      DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js", line 870, in Handler.prototype.process
        nextValue = this.onResolve.call(undefined, nextValue);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 86, in startup/</<
        run(options);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 145, in run
        let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 684, in main
        return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
        var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 591, in require
        freeze(load(loader, module));
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 59, in null
        require("./util/deprecate").deprecateUsage(
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
        let stack = get().slice(2);
    JavaScript error: resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/data/c2c_options_menu_localization.js, line 189: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at erewards.erewards_admin.main(erewards_admin.java:14)
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
    DAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"7.3.16540.9015","st":1405342340000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0","st":1424934772238,"mt":1424934771658}},"winreg-app-global":{"fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Fiddler2\\FiddlerHook","e":false,"v":"2.4.8.3","st":1415012376210,"mt":1406724252000}}}
    1425038534487   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1425038534492   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534493   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534500   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.3.16540.9015
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/pcs/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3272192605644315779webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
    JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
    *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
    1425038536584   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
      DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js", line 870, in Handler.prototype.process
        nextValue = this.onResolve.call(undefined, nextValue);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 86, in startup/</<
        run(options);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 145, in run
        let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 684, in main
        return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
        var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 591, in require
        freeze(load(loader, module));
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 59, in null
        require("./util/deprecate").deprecateUsage(
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
        let stack = get().slice(2);
    JavaScript error: resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/data/c2c_options_menu_localization.js, line 189: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

    Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
    System info: host: 'pcs-PC', ip: '192.168.1.64', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at erewards.erewards_admin.main(erewards_admin.java:14)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    DAD38A}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi","e":true,"v":"7.3.16540.9015","st":1405342340000},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"36.0","st":1424934772238,"mt":1424934771658}},"winreg-app-global":{"fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Fiddler2\\FiddlerHook","e":false,"v":"2.4.8.3","st":1415012376210,"mt":1406724252000}}}
    1425038534487   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
    1425038534492   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534493   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1425038534500   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.3.16540.9015
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1425038534563   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
    1425038534565   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/pcs/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3272192605644315779webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
    JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
    *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
    1425038536584   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
      DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js", line 870, in Handler.prototype.process
        nextValue = this.onResolve.call(undefined, nextValue);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 86, in startup/</<
        run(options);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 145, in run
        let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 684, in main
        return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
        var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 591, in require
        freeze(load(loader, module));
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
        result = load(loader, module);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 318, in load
        evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 267, in evaluate
        : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 59, in null
        require("./util/deprecate").deprecateUsage(
      File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
        let stack = get().slice(2);
    JavaScript error: resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/data/c2c_options_menu_localization.js, line 189: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: this is very basic statement dont know what's going wrong and where?

Comment: Have you configured everything properly?

Comment: "unable to fetch" is *not* a description of what happened and how it failed to live up to your expectations. Did you get a compile error? Then show us that error. Did you get a runtime error? Then show us that stack trace.

Comment: Also, can you comment on why your code is triplicated? Did you post it that way by mistake? Or are you trying to compile it triplicated?

Comment: that was posted 3 times by mistake. I am getting below errors:

Comment: please check the error that I have pasted below the main code. I got this error after the run.

Comment: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Either need to try with chrome instead of firefox.
My selenium version is 2.44.0

Comment: any suggestions ...i have tried building the program by 2 different selenium build one the latest one that selenium 2.44.0 and second the old one 2.41.0.

Comment: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Comment: I think downgrading the firefox version frm 36 to 31 will help solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem here with Firefox 36.0.1 and Selenium Firefox Driver 2.43.1. Updating it to 2.45.0 solved the problem.

Comment: This may be an occurrence of [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8399), which was fixed in 2.45.